# Compare elements in multiple pandas Series, given as a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have a multiple Series, given as a list. Number of series may vary.

```
s1 = pandas.Series(data=['Bob', 'John', '10', 10, 'i'])
s2 = pandas.Series(data=['John', 'John', 10, 10, 'j'])
s3 = pandas.Series(data=['Bob', 'John', '10', 10, 'k'])
series = [s1,s2,s3]
```

What I want is to check list with a series if elements are equal and get back list with an indexes or numpy.array with booleans.

What I have tried:

```
numpy.equal.reduce([s for s in series])

or

numpy.equal.reduce([s.values for s in series])
```

But with a given series i get:

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

I expected:

```
array([ False,  True,  False,  True,  False])
```

Are there any elegant way to do this job, without constructing big iterating methods?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply construct a df and check number of unique:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(series).nunique().eq(1))

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Or as an array:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(series).nunique().eq(1).to_numpy())

[False  True False  True False]
```